# Parser Error Message when adding new C# Webform with codebehind inside .vbproj solution

Tags: c#, vb.net, webforms

So I've inherited a .vbproj that was created using Visual Web Developer Express 2010. Inside the project file there are aspx.vb and aspx.cs files. The program works fine until I’ve added new C# class. Here are the steps that I did when I created the new C# webform and class:
1.  I’ve created the new C# webform (CreateOrder.aspx) and the code behind file (CreateOrder.aspx.cs) in a separate project.

> I did this because Visual Web Developer Express 2010 won’t let me add
>   C# webform and class (.cs) inside the existing .vbproj.

2.  Then I copy and pasted the C# webform with the code behind file to the existing .vbproj solution.
3.  When I run the program and open the webform.aspx, I’m getting the following error:

```
[Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'CreateOrder'.<br>
<%@ Page Title="Create Order" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="CreateOrder.aspx.cs" Inherits="CreateOrder"%>]
```

[Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eaq2V.jpg)

I understand that it couldn’t find the CreateOrder class which is clearly inside the code behind class (CreateOrder.aspx.cs). I have it declared as `public class CreateOrder : System.Web.UI.Page`
The weird thing is there’s a lot of existing C# webforms with code behind class inside the existing .vbproj. Not sure why my newly created class is throwing the Parser error message. Please help guys. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the web.config file. The code behind files are probably being stored in separate folders under the App_Code directory. You may need to move the new page's code behind file and also change the CodeBehind attribute in the page so that everything can be wired up.

Comment: Hi Martin, adding the code behind under App_Code directory works fine. However, I'm having another error when adding a textbox or any other objects. Let say I added txtSearch texbox, the error is CS0103: The name 'txtSearch' does not exist in the current context. How do I fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this error showing up in Visual Studio? Or, do you get the error when you actually try to view the page in your browser? This helps narrow down where the issue is coming from.

Comment: The error shows up when I tried to view the page in the browser. I setup a local IIS server from my laptop, I'm running the program through Visual Web Developer Express 2010.

Comment: It's working now, I just need to instantiate the txtSearch TextBox object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try importing your `CreateOrder` class. This will link the assembly for that class to the current project.

Comment: Hi, importing the class works perfect, thank you. However, when I try adding a textbox, for example txtSearch, I'm getting an error saying Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'txtSearch' does not exist in the current context. My class doesn't have the aspx.designer.cs. To summarize, I have the following: CreateOrder.cs class inside the App_Code folder, and CreateOrder.aspx within the main project directory. I appreciate your help.

Comment: It sounds like you need to declare your Textbox programmatically since you don't have the designer.cs file. That error means that the compiler can't find a variable or method of any kind that matches the name "txtSearch." I don't know of any reason right off that programmatically adding your visual components won't work. You'd do something like this: `Textbox txtSearch = new Textbox();` (may not be exact syntax, but you get the picture).

Comment: Perfect, that works, I had to instantiate the txtSearch text box. Thanks for your help!